# $\Hom_\Set(G_1 \times G_2,R) \cong \Hom_\Set(G_1,R) \otimes_R \Hom_\Set(G_2,R)$?

Tags: category-theory

$
\newcommand{\Hom}{\mathrm{Hom}}
\newcommand{\Set}{\mathbf{Set}}
$
I find this isomorphism in one example in my class notes, but I can't see when or why it holds. If someone could help me with it I would appreciate it.

Let $G_1,G_2$ be groups and $R$ a ring, then: $$\Hom_\Set(G_1 \times G_2,R) \cong \Hom_\Set(G_1,R) \otimes_R \Hom_\Set(G_2,R)$$

How does one prove this?

Comment: You use groups, but you don't exploit the group structure at all. It is just the fact that for any finite sets $X,Y$, $$\mathrm{Mor}_{Set}(X,R)\simeq \bigoplus_X R$$ and $$\left(\bigoplus_X R\right)\otimes_R \left(\bigoplus_Y R\right)\simeq \bigoplus_{X\times Y} R$$ as $R$-modules, and the result follows.

Comment: This is only true if at least one of $G_1$ or $G_2$ is finite (I'm most comfortable taking both $G_1$ and $G_2$ finite though).

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Thanks. But what is "Mor"? I never saw it before.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat you meant "Hom" right?

Comment: It is standard for the set of morphisms between objects in a category, you'll find it in the wikipedia entry on category theory. You could write Hom aswell, but I reserve Hom for more algebraic settings than the category of sets.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat ah, good to know. Anyway, I see that it's simple now, but since the question is there you might as well make your comment into an answer so that I can close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a comment made into an answer.

---

For finite sets $X$,
$$\mathrm{Mor}_{\mathbf{Set}}(X,R)\simeq\prod_X R\simeq\oplus_XR$$
are isomorphic as $(R,R)$-bimodules, and for if both $X$ and $Y$ are finite, then
$$\left(\oplus_X R\right)\otimes_R\left(\oplus_X R\right)\simeq\oplus_{X\times Y}R$$
again as $(R,R)$-bimodules.